# added module keeps going after reboot

Tags: drivers, kernel

I have been reading through many posts and google searches to try and answer my question. But alas, nothing appears to be working.

I have a unit running 12.04 LTS, and a manufacturers 3rd Party driver source.

I have used `make install` to compile and install the module driver, and can see it is in the correct path:

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/char/
```

I checked the `/etc/modules` file and manually added the module name and updated `update-initramfs -u` and rebooted.

Check `lsmod` and it has not been reloaded after reboot.

I have been looking at this for some time now and going slow mad.

Can anyone offer some advise on what I am missing? Or what I should be doing?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you load that module manually with `modprobe <module-name>`? Also check the output of `dmesg` and search for the module name in there.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for replying. modprobe is ok, and dmesg | grep is showing it. but it fails to persist/load on reboot
edit: Looks like i am now getting an error:
    <module-name>: module verification failed: signature and/key missing - tainting kernel

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this.

So what i did:

Make #driver
Make install
modified the /etc/modules to include the module
insmod the module to load in to ensure it is ok.
depmod
reboot
done

:):)